# Why do so many gems end in fu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why do so many gems end in fu?

Not that this make it clear to me, but here is what Google says ["define: fu"](http://www.google.com/search?q=define:+fu).

Comment: Not really programming related, but: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=23068

Comment: I always thought it was a nod to the fact that that obstacle was overcome, like "attachment fu! I can attach shit now!"

Comment: They always want their gems to look "funky" i.e why its fu

Comment: And funnily enough, kung maps to "achievement" and fu to "man/human". 
Which gives "attachment man"
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kung_fu_(term)

Comment: Some more trivia on naming schemes in the Rails (and Ruby world):

In the beginning, a lot of Rails plugins where named like acts_as_whatever (this was started by a few plugins by Rails core members e.g. acts_as_taggable). After that, there was the fu naming scheme: whatever-fu (the explained playon kung-fu). And finally, there was the can_haz wave: can_haz_whatever (obviously inspired by lolcats/icanhazcheezeburger)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is, as @meagar said, a play on 'kung-fu'. It's an old, old practice. A few plugins for the GIMP are called ***-fu, and you can hear people say that their vim-fu is strong, to say that someone is particularly skilled with vim.

Comment: I've often heard it used as google-fu, meaning one's skill at finding things with a search engine.

Comment: @jeanne that is indeed one more example :)

Answer (score 1):

It comes from a trend in the English language consisting on attaching the particle -fu to an activity, normally to indicate that it there's a certain degree of skill involved. You can use these constructions the same way you would refer to martial arts (kung-fu):

"His math-fu is impressive"

"Can you solve this by doing some of your planning-fu?"

I believe the first rails gem that had this "lingüistic feature" was [technoweenie's attachment-fu](http://svn.techno-weenie.net/projects/plugins/attachment_fu/README). It was a very useful gem, so it became widely popular. So it was imitated in other gems.